# Google DNS / OpenDNS - See the IP address of the answering server?

Tags: dns, nameservers, opendns

Forgive the poor title... I'll do my best to explain

Working with Google DNS or OpenDNS *(as they're both anycast)* - is there a command in Windows or Linux where I can do a lookup and have the IP address or hostname of the actual server that resolved the lookup returned?

The reason I ask is I'm trying to find where my queries to 8.8.8.8 are actually resolved. While Google list my country as having DNS infrastructure, I have a feeling it's only a cache and the queries are being resolved in Europe

Thx

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't find that.

Actually, if the server already has those info you want in its database/cache,it will reply you directly. Otherwise, it would query other domain name servers (may through Root domain name servers and/or other authoritative) to get DNS records, then update its database/cache and also reply you.

Comment: Hmm... okay thanks. I do recall OpenDNS had a feature years ago that could show you which of their geo-servers were actually answering your DNS lookups. It would return the hostname of the server which were usually abreviated with location, example London being lon_xyz

Comment: I was using the tools from [ipleak.net](https://ipleak.net) which correctly identify that I am using Google DNS but they go on to list a range of Google servers based in Belgium and the Netherlands while I'm in Ireland. I have asked the providers of ipleak about this and am awaiting a response